# Adding my app to autoplay list using C#

Tags: c#

How can i add my app to autoplay list (e.g. for music files)?
How can i add it to general options(Where open folder to view files is)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a file association for the music file types (mp3 etc).

The [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx), shows how to do this programatically.

Kindness,

Dan